# Laravel return value of updating a model

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

what I want to do is when the update is done, the data of the whole Model is returned.

I am registering and updating the database.

what i want `when the data is updated` i want it to return me all the data.

`return response()->json($category)`;

the return returns `1`, what I want to do is show the updated data instead of 1

```
$category = Category::where('id', $id)->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'slug' => $request->slug,
            'is_home' => $request->is_home,
            'language' => $request->language,
            'status' => $request->status,
        ]);
        return response()->json($category);
```

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to do, add the error. add pieces of code that you've already tried etc. this question is incomplete

Comment: the return returns `1`, what I want to do is show the updated data instead of 1

Comment: `$model = Category::find($id); $model->update(...); return $model;` ...

Comment: save the query result to the array and print data of array. $updated = Category::where('users')->where('id', 1)->update(['votes' => 123]); dd($updated );

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of your object Category and save, that should work

```
$category = Category::find($id);
$category->title = $request->title;
$category->slug = $request->slug;
$category->is_home = $request->is_home;
$category->language = $request->language;
$category->status = $request->status;
$category->save();
return response()->json($category);
```

The return of the update() method is a boolean, not the object.

Comment: I don't want to do it this way, is there an easier way?

Comment: Extend the base model and modify the update() function if it's what you want.